# error: package com.gdacciaro.iOSDialog does not exist

Tags: android, class

When I build my android project on the android studio, I'm getting these errors. Anyone know how to fix them?

> error: package com.gdacciaro.iOSDialog does not exist
>
> import com.gdacciaro.iOSDialog.iOSDialog;
>
> error: cannot find symbol class iOSDialog

```java
if (selectedPhotoImg.length() == 0) {
     final iOSDialog iOSDialog = new iOSDialog(this.getActivity());
     iOSDialog.setTitle( getString(R.string.add_photo_required));
                    iOSDialog.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.photo_info_required));
     iOSDialog.setPositiveLabel("OK");
     iOSDialog.setBoldPositiveLabel(true);
     iOSDialog.setPositiveListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
              iOSDialog.dismiss();
         }
     });

     iOSDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the gradle reference to the library you are using? Go to your build.gradle file (app level) and add

```
implementation 'com.gdacciaro:iosdialog:1.0.3'
```

then sync the project with Gradle files, build it and the import should work.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: It was 'com.gdacciaro:iosdialog:1.0.2'